# Webservice request with php behind http-proxy

Tags: php, web-services, http-proxy

We have a web-application written in PHP + JavaScript + MariaDB 10, that works under APACHE v2.4. The application run only on LAN for internal use.

The app can call openstreetmap 'nominatim': *nominatim.openstreetmap.org*, as a GET webservice query in order to obtain geographical information about a specific map area selected by user, in my case in JSON format

I used `file_get_contents`:

```
$request = 'https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=verdi&format=json&viewbox=11.748881281415,44.83786393229,11.908766702946,44.91246161156&bounded=1&addressdetails=1&limit=1&polygon_geojson=1';
$result = file_get_contents($request, false);
```

Normally everything work very well but not when I try to run on LAN that use a http-proxy server for internet connection.

I spent time to search a solution but I'm a bit confused:

The same query string that don't work on web-application, work well on browser configured to use proxy in the same computer.
I tried to analyze both php (trough cUrl) and browser headers but I don't understand what is the correct way to resolve the issue:

1. It is possible to use cUrl or another library with known proxy credential and make a workly web-service request?
2. Or it is better to ask to network administrator (if is possible) to set a http-proxy exception for the domain nominatim.openstreetmap.org?

Any help will be appreciated